# Adding a day to a date with NSCalendar

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift2, nscalendar

I'm trying to add a day to another (it works perfectly until I saw something).

For the week 6 in 2016 (starting the 30th of january), if I had a day to this date, it shows me the 31st of december 2015.

Can you explain me what I'm doing wrong ?

Here is the code (you can put it in a playground):

```
let weekToDisplay = 6
let yearToDisplay = 2016

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comp = NSDateComponents()
comp.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
comp.weekOfYear = weekToDisplay
comp.year = yearToDisplay

let dateToIncrement = calendar.dateFromComponents(comp)! // "Jan 31, 2016, 12:00 AM
var incrementedDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: dateToIncrement, options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)! // "Jan 1, 2016, 12:00 AM"

print(dateToIncrement) // "2016-01-30 23:00:00 +0000\n"
print(incrementedDate) // "2015-12-31 23:00:00 +0000\n"
```

Last thing, when you print the date, it's not the same as showed in the playground when executing that particular line of code, why ? (see the comments)

Comment: You don't want to wrap the addition.

Comment: @rmaddy's answer is the correct one. It's clear and to the point. (Voted). You should accept that one rather than William's, since his initial answer was not the right way to do it, and his updated answer is muddy and confused.

Comment: @DuncanC really my updated answer is confused?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is the option to wrap the date components. You don't want that. Simply do:

```
let weekToDisplay = 6
let yearToDisplay = 2016

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comp = NSDateComponents()
comp.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
comp.weekOfYear = weekToDisplay
comp.year = yearToDisplay

let dateToIncrement = calendar.dateFromComponents(comp)! // "Jan 31, 2016, 12:00 AM
var incrementedDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: dateToIncrement, options: [])! // "Jan 1, 2016, 12:00 AM"

print(dateToIncrement)
print(incrementedDate)
```

Comment: This is far and away the best answer (voted) and you should accept this one instead of the other one.

Comment: Ok, I took it as the right answer. Maybe i need to check Apple's documentation to see what the options mean. Thank you @rmaddy, I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

to solve your problem, here you go:

```
let weekToDisplay = 6
let yearToDisplay = 2016

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let comp = NSDateComponents()
comp.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
comp.weekOfYear = weekToDisplay
comp.year = yearToDisplay

let dateToIncrement = calendar.dateFromComponents(comp)! // "Jan 31, 2016, 12:00 AM

print(dateToIncrement) // "2016-01-30 23:00:00 +0000\n"


let incrementedDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: dateToIncrement, options: .MatchStrictly) // "Feb 1, 2016, 12:00 AM"
```

Comment: I think `NSCalendar` handles daylight savings time better

Comment: Never do calendar math by adding `NSTimeInterval` values.

Comment: It works, but if comments say to not use it, is there another alternative ?

Comment: @user3497168 i added another solution for you, the updated solution is much better

Comment: This answer is still wrong. It still talks about using `NSTimeInterval` and it still incorrectly wraps the date components.

Comment: @rmaddy sweetheart, i hope you check again, in the updated version there is no nstiminterval, check `tomorrow2` it has nothing to do with nstimeinterval

Comment: @WilliamKinaan You changed your answer after my comment. And don't call me sweetheart. Why don't you remove the 1st half of your answer?

Comment: @rmaddy i just deleted the line of the nstimeinterval because it was unrleated to the answer.  you didn't even read the updated answer to see that tmorrow2 has nothign to do with nstimeinterval

Comment: I did read it. As I said, your answer still has info about using a time interval. And you needlessly introduced a new variable instead of fixed the original variable (`incrementDate`). It's very confusing. Plus, you never actual stated what the problem and solution is.

Comment: @rmaddy yet it is 100% correct. the variables are from the OP.

Comment: @WilliamKinaan I'm trying to help. 1) You really should remove the 1st half of your answer since it is a bad solution. 2) Your update is not 100% correct. You didn't fix the problem code. You instead added a new variable with the proper solution so it's not the same variables from the OP. 3) You never explained what was wrong and what needed to be fixed. A good answer explains things. A good answer is just a bunch of code (correct or not) with no explanation. It would be so simple to make your answer a good answer instead of a marginally correct answer.